# Hyper-V - Windows 10 VM loses network connection after session disconnect

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I have Hyper-V running on Poweredge T30 running Windows 10 Pro. I have created a few virtual machines all running Windows 10 Pro. They are all sharing the same network adapter as the host machine. Everything seems to work perfectly. The VM network connections are solid and services are available across my LAN.

BUT, if I connect to any virtual machine and then disconnect without using the "sign out" command, the VM instantly loses it's network. Hyper-V manager shows the machine is still running, but it's IP address disappears (from the networking tab of the VM details view in the manager) and any attempt to connect times out. After that, if I "reset" the virtual machine it comes right back up.

If I connect and "sign out", the VM stays up and keeps working as expected - this only happens if I close the session without signing out. I have tried this with 3 separate VMs running Windows 10 and it happens consistently every time. I don't see anything in the Event Logs of either the VM or the host machine when this happens.

I should be able to leave a user logged into the VM right?

Note: This behavior happens whether I connect and disconnect from within the Hyper-V manager or by using RDP from another computer on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue - though I have not seen it reported anywhere and this question is getting zero love here :) - I was finally able to resolve it by unchecking the "Allow enhanced session mode" in Hyper-V Settings:

[image: Hyper-V Session Mode Settings]

Comment: Sorry but this is just ridiculous.  Unchecking "allow enhanced session mode" disabled required features like being able to copy/paste between the host and VM.  (Also can you tell I'm ticked off that randomly I will stop being able to RDP into my VM for no good reason?)